# output many chars (including ASCII) at once?

Tags: c, arrays, char, output

So guys, I'm working on a program where I need to output a 2D `int` array (I made this an `int`-array, because I work with the values at some other points). In my first attempt I tried to print the correct char (including ASCII) for the `int` values:

```
void printField(){                              
    int i,j;
    system("CLS");
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
       for(j=0; j<142; j++) {
            if(field[i][j]==0){
                printf(" ");                    
            }
            if(field[i][j]==9){
                printf("%c",219);                       
            }
            if(field[i][j]==2){ 
                printf("%c",219);                   
            }
            if(field[i][j]==1){
                printf(" ");                    
            }
            if(field[i][j]==6){
                printf(" ");                    
            }
            if(field[i][j]==7){
                printf("%c",207);               
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
}
```

The Problem is, that the screen is flickering, because I have to print that field pretty fast and it prints character after character. So I started researching ([here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/90996-ascii-character-conversion/)  and [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcat.php) may help) and tried to solve this by printing out all at once (using `strcat()`):

```
void printField(){                              
    int i,j;
    char toPrint[10000];
    system("CLS");
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
       for(j=0; j<142; j++) {
            if(field[i][j]==0){
                strcat(toPrint," ");                    
            }
            if(field[i][j]==9){
                char temp[2];
                temp[0]=char(219);
                strcat(toPrint,temp);               
            }
            if(field[i][j]==2){
                char temp[2];
                temp[0]=char(219);
                strcat(toPrint,temp);               
            }
            if(field[i][j]==1){
                strcat(toPrint," ");                    
            }
            if(field[i][j]==6){
                strcat(toPrint," ");                    
            }
            if(field[i][j]==7){
                char temp[2];
                temp[0]=char(207);
                strcat(toPrint,temp);               
            }
       }
       strcat(toPrint,"\n");
   }
   printf("%s\n", toPrint);
}
```

With DEV-C++ I don't get any Errors, but the output is totally not what it should be. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output? What was supposed to be the output?

Comment: Also try using the function memset() on the toPrint array before looping since there may still be garbage characters in that array.

Comment: if you turn that into a array of `char`, you can still work with the values. And it will make your life a lot easier when printing.

Comment: ASCII characters have codes from 0 to 127.

Comment: `strcat` requires the 1st parameter to be a valid, null terminated string. You pass a buffer filled with garbage. Fix this by initializing `char toPrint[n] = "";`. Also avoid dumping 10k bytes on the stack, you might get stack overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
void printField()
{
    int i,j;
    int n = 0;
    char toPrint[52*(142+1)+1];

    system("CLS");

    for (i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<142; j++)
        {
            switch (field[i][j])
            {
                case 0: toPrint[n++] = ' '; break;
                case 9: toPrint[n++] = 219; break;
                case 2: toPrint[n++] = 219; break;
                case 1: toPrint[n++] = ' '; break;
                case 6: toPrint[n++] = ' '; break;
                case 7: toPrint[n++] = 207; break;
            }
        }
        toPrint[n++] = '\n';
    }

    toPrint[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",toPrint);
}
```

Comment: Works too (even with the right characters). So the solution is to manually concat those chars without `strcat()`? Another Question: '\n' and '\0' are **one** char in the chararray, right? What does that mean for the size? 
`toPrint[53*142+1]`

Comment: @Wondertree: 1. `strcat` takes two null-terminated strings (array of characters ending with `'\0'`) as input arguments. In your code, you have provided an argument which does comply with that, leading to undefined behavior (most likely, memory access violation, or reading/writing "junk" data). 2. Yes, `'\n'` and `'\0'` are **one** character each. 3. `toPrint[52*142+1]` means that the `toPrint` array consists of 52*142+1 entries, which is the exact amount needed in your case.

Comment: Ah okay, got the first one, but i still wonder about the size. If i have 52*142 characters + '\n' after every 52 chars + '\0' at the end,  shouldnt it be [53*142+1] then?

Comment: @Wondertree: You're absolutely right. I've changed it to `52*(142+1)+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there was many wrong things in your code, so I had to rewrite it to this:

```
void printField(){                              
    int i,j;
    char toPrint[10000];
    char* current = toPrint; // pointer to beginning of char array
    system("CLS");
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
       for(j=0; j<142; j++) {
            if(field[i][j]==0){
                *current++ = ' ';
            }
            if(field[i][j]==9){
                *current++ = '\xDB';
            }
            if(field[i][j]==2){
                *current++ = '\xDB';
            }
            if(field[i][j]==1){
                *current++ = ' ';
            }
            if(field[i][j]==6){
                *current++ = ' ';
            }
            if(field[i][j]==7){
                *current++ = '\xCF';
            }
       }
       *current++ = '\n';
   }
   *current = '\0';
   puts(toPrint);
}
```

**Edit:** fixed wrong chars

Comment: Thanks, works nearly perfect (i get other chars). I'm not used to work with pointers, but makes sense so far. Still, would be great if you could explain why my version didnt work.